# Select with count on 3 tables

Tags: sql, select, join, count

I need your help for a particular `SELECT` on 3 tables. I'm not skilled on `SQL` so it's a difficult `SELECT` for me, since I have to apply `COUNT` (I suppose) to the query.

I show you my tables:[image]

I need to know how many **contacts** there are in the database (all the contacts!!!!) and how many **photos** and **videos** are bound to any contact.

I should get a result similar to this:

```
-----------------------------------
| ID | NAME       | PHOTO | VIDEO |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | MARK       | 3     | 1     |
-----------------------------------
| ID | LISA       | 2     | 0     |
-----------------------------------
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach, if you are hesitant about duplicates in the query you can use a sql function and pass type parameter as a string. If you have uncertain number of types (VIDEO, PHOTO, TEXT etc) you need to redesign the output table format (I would go with the following tuple TYPE, CONTACT_ID, COUNT), or at the worst case go with dynamic query construction.

```
select c.ID, c.NAME, 
(select count(*) from CONTACT_MEDIA cm join MEDIA m on 
m.ID = cm.ID_MEDIA and m.TYPE = 'PHOTO' where cm.ID_CONTACT = c.ID) as PHOTO, 
(select count(*) from CONTACT_MEDIA cm join MEDIA m on 
m.ID = cm.ID_MEDIA and m.TYPE = 'VIDEO' where cm.ID_CONTACT = c.ID) as VIDEO
from CONTACT c
```

Comment: Np. I dont wont to edit my answer once again. But I want to comment on dynamic approach. In that case you need to find all unique types then iterate over them adding a new output col definition to the query in form of string, after that you can run constructed query using 'sp_executesql'. It will work, but it's not efficient and hard to consume from the client perspective. But if you have no options then it's a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query , this will give you exact result

```
select contact_media.ID_Contact, contact.Name, count(M1.ID) as 'PHOTO', COUNT(M2.ID) as 'VIDEO' from Contact inner join contact_media on Contact.ID=contact_media.ID_Contact
left outer join media M1 on contact_media.ID_Media=M1.ID and M1.TYPE='PHOTO'
left outer join media M2 on contact_media.ID_Media=M2.ID and M2.TYPE='VIDEO'
 group by contact_media.ID_Contact, contact.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help man. I tried your query but there is a problem. If a contact has no photo/video it is not "taken" from the database. I need all contacts on the database. 
I should I edit your query to get all contacts?